# Mocking an if condition within a for loop in JUnit

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock a method using Mockito and JUnit. For some reason it keeps saying that the embedded method is never being invoked, despite the test fulfilling the if statement.

Here is my method that I am testing:

```
    public List<LifeProduct> prune(List<LifeProduct> products) {
        for (LifeProduct product : products) {
            int id = product.getProductAnalyticsIdentifier();
            boolean deleteAnnuity = id > 10014;
            boolean deleteLifeInsurance = product.getLifeInsurance()
                .getHighLevelLifeInsuranceGroupName()
                .equals("string");
            
            if (deleteAnnuity) {
                annuityService.deleteAnnuityById(id);
            }
            if (deleteLifeInsurance) {
                lifeInsuranceService.deleteLifeInsuranceById(id);
            }
        }
        
        return products;
    }
```

and here is my test with the iterator setup:

```
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  
        when(mockList.iterator()).thenReturn(mockIterator);
        when(mockIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true, false);
        when(mockIterator.next()).thenReturn(mockProduct);
    }

    @Test
    public final void testPrune() throws Exception {
        for (LifeProduct mockProduct : mockList) {
            mockProduct.setProductAnalyticsIdentifier(99999999);
            doNothing().when(annuityService).deleteAnnuityById(anyInt());
            List<LifeProduct> response = lifeProductDelegate.prune(mockList);
            assertNotNull(response);
            verify(annuityService).deleteAnnuityById(anyInt());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You method is never called, because your own test method wastes the first mocked result of `mockIterator.hasNext()`. Why do you even _use_ the mock in the test itself? That's usually a bad style.

Comment: Sorry, on the newer side to Java. Could you expand on the test case wasting the first mocked result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test has two issues:

#### You're using the `mockList` and therefore use one of the two values for `mockIterator.hasNext()`

You say that when `mockIterator.hasNext()` is called, it should first return `true` and then `false`. The issue here is that your test method iterates over `mockList` and therefore needs to call `mockIterator.hasNext()` and then uses the first, the `true`, value. The tested method `#prune()` then also attempts to iterate the list, but will only get the second, the `false`, value, thus skipping the loop. You don't need the loop in your test method, so you can and should remove it.

#### You incorrectly setup `mockProduct`

The second issue is `mockProduct.setProductAnalyticsIdentifier(99999999)`. `mockProduct` is a mock, so the methods don't do anything when not configured for example via `when(mockProduct...)...`. So the value 99999999 is not stored anywhere and `#getProductAnalyticsIdentifier()` in the test returns 0, the default value. What you actually want to do is to configure the getter method, for example with:

```
when(mockProduct.getProductAnalyticsIdentifier()).thenReturn(999999);
```

Now the `mockProduct` will return that value when `#prune()` asks for the id and later compares it with 10014.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and clarification! Definitely makes a lot more sense now. Additionally, there was a problem with me trying to access the lifeInsurance when I didn't mock it which was leading to a NullPointerException as well.